# Path statement leaves a value in moved-from state?

Tags: rust

The surprisingly behaving code fragment:

```
let p = &mut 1i;
p; // note: `p` moved here because it has type `&mut int`, which is non-copyable
p; // error: use of moved value: `p`
```

Is this a bug or an intended behaviour?

Comment: Does it matter? Is there real world code where this results in a problem?

Comment: @A.B. Yes, it does. Who cares about real world.

Comment: It does seem strange, I opened [#16502](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/16502) to hopefully fix (at least clarify).

Comment: @dbaupp The fact that `let _ = p;` doesn't move is equally surprising. For me `let _ = p;` looks like "make value of p inaccessible by moving it somewhere but keep it alive". Though I'm not sure I understand `_` correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's intended. `&mut T` is an owned type, so when you mention it as an expression it moves. You don't normally notice this because methods calls have their own reborrowing rules that give the callee a temporary mutable borrow of the `self` value (to avoid the annoyance of your mutable reference moving away).

Comment: A 'manual reborrow', `&mut *p` will sometimes work around problems like this.