# What does a statement with a single variable name and a semicolon mean in Rust?

Tags: rust, move

I'm playing with Rust and found the following example:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = [3, 4, 5].to_vec();
    x;
    println!("{:?}", x);
}
```

The compiler tells me

```
18 |     let mut x = [3, 4, 5].to_vec();
   |         ----- move occurs because `x` has type `std::vec::Vec<i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
21 |     x;
   |     - value moved here
22 |     println!("{:?}", x);
   |                      ^ value borrowed here after move
```

It seems the statement `x;` caused `x` moved to somewhere and it can't be used after that. Where is the move destination and what exactly happend here?

I searched around and can't find any information explaining this. Maybe I'm using the wrong keyword.

Btw, I'm using this version of Rust: `rustc 1.41.0-nightly (99b89533d 2019-12-16)`

Comment: I have no idea what the actual issue is (I would have expected the compiler to remove that line), but _maybe_ it's related to a particular version (or not).  It might be useful to edit your question to include which version of the Rust compiler you're using, just in case.

Comment: @Jarak Thanks for reminding! I added the version info.

Comment: you're all over the good questions today

Comment: if x implemented `Copy`, I'm guessing it would call that that implementation. Might help

Comment: @JoelBerkeley haha, I'm really new to Rust.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25313583/path-statement-leaves-a-value-in-moved-from-state)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Path statement leaves a value in moved-from state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25313583/path-statement-leaves-a-value-in-moved-from-state)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`x;` is [an expression statement](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/statements.html#expression-statements) that:

> An expression statement is one that evaluates an expression and ignores its result.

The expression here is in turn [a place expression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#place-expressions-and-value-expressions) which:

> Moving out of a place expression that evaluates to a local variable, the location is deinitialized and cannot be read from again until it is reinitialized.

So after that you can't use it again. In fact, if you compile the following:

```rust
fn main() {
    let x = vec![42];
    x;
}
```

to MIR:

```
fn  main() -> () {
    let mut _0: (); // return place in scope 0 at src/main.rs:1:11: 1:11
    let _1: std::vec::Vec<i32>; // "x" in scope 0 at src/main.rs:2:9: 2:10

    ...

    bb1: {
        StorageDead(_2); // bb1[0]: scope 0 at <::alloc::macros::vec macros>:2:62: 2:63
        StorageLive(_5); // bb1[1]: scope 1 at src/main.rs:3:5: 3:6
        _5 = move _1;    // bb1[2]: scope 1 at src/main.rs:3:5: 3:6
        drop(_5) -> bb2; // bb1[3]: scope 1 at src/main.rs:3:6: 3:7
    }
}
```

You can clearly see it is moved into a temporary variable and that temporary variable is promptly dropped.

Comment: So, `x;` is effectively the same as `let _ = x;`?

Comment: @Cerberus not really. Since `let _ = x;` doesn't bind to anything, it is somewhat more like `drop(x);` whereas `x;` is akin to `let tmp = x; drop(tmp);`.